# How to read result from raw SQL command

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Question updated :

I am using C# + SQL Server + EF6
I need to execute a raw SQL commands to the database, for which there is no entity.

```
string query2 = "SELECT s.Name, t.State, Count(*) [Nb], 
AVG(t.Duration) [Avg], 
MIN(t.Duration) [Min], 
MAX(t.Duration) [Max] from ...";
```

How to get the result of the query in EF6 ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: why the double opening parenthesis in this `(("SELECT`

Comment: Use [`SqlQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery.aspx), not `ExecuteSqlCommand`.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C first result on google search "c# result from sql server"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody found the answer. But it is easier to downvote than solving code issues !
So, here is the answer, i hope it will help other guys who encounter the same problem.
1 / Assuming you build a query which creates a table with custom columns named "Name, State, Nb, Avg, Min, Max :

```
string query2 = "SELECT s.Name, t.State, Count(*) [Nb], 
AVG(t.Duration) [Avg], 
MIN(t.Duration) [Min], 
MAX(t.Duration) [Max] from ...";
```

2 / you have to create a class for the mapping from database to object :

```
public class stats
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 State { get; set; }
    public Int32 Nb { get; set; }
    public Int32 Avg { get; set; }
    public Int32 Min { get; set; }
    public Int32 Max { get; set; }
}
```

3 / then you execute the query :

```
IEnumerable<stats> data = db.Database.SqlQuery<stats>(query2);
```

db is the class which extends DbContext